# Ruby Including image from Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

This is the ruby code from my web site that works great LOCALLY:

```
    <% slika = Refinery::Page.find('torte-za-rodendan') %>
        <%= link_to (slika), :class => "hp_product" do %>   
        <%= image_tag slika.key_image.url, :width=>"154", :height=>"100"  %>
        <h2>Za rođendan</h2>  <!-- <%= slika.title %> -->
<% end %>
```

The problem is - I have to give it a link to the picture that was uploaded on Amazon S3 so that users can view the picture GLOBALLY.

Can anyone please give me advice how can I modify my code in order to achieve that?

Comment: is key_image saving the correct url for the s3 image? and what exactly is not working?

Comment: Thanks Kyle C, but I've solved the problem.
I would appreciate if you could help me concerning this matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050164/going-live-domain-name-heroku-refinery-cms

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved - everything is solved with S3 Amazon coniguration